# On blog share in facebook the thumb image not comming

Tags: wordpress, facebook

if i share the blog post in facebook it shows the following like image. My blog in wordpress and i also check in the facebook debug mode.
[image]

in facebook debug mode it shows the following error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check you theme header for tag

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://../share.jpg" />
```

If you this tag are missing you should add this and add link to static image or post featured image.

If you find this tag twice, you should remove one. Also this can be fixed by installing **Yoast SEO** plugin.

Comment: this tag is present and only once it present.